# Swift type conversion

Tags: macos, swift, casting

How can I convert `NSApplicationPresentationOptions` to `AnyObject?`? The `as` doesn't work here.
I want to call:

```
func enterFullScreenMode(_ screen: NSScreen, withOptions options: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
```

I have:

```
let presOptions: NSApplicationPresentationOptions =
    .HideDock                  |   // Dock is entirely unavailable. Spotlight menu is disabled.
    .AutoHideMenuBar           |   // Menu Bar appears when moused to.
    .DisableAppleMenu          |   // All Apple menu items are disabled.
    .DisableProcessSwitching   |   // Cmd+Tab UI is disabled. All Exposé functionality is also disabled.
    .DisableForceQuit          |   // Cmd+Opt+Esc panel is disabled.
    .DisableSessionTermination |   // PowerKey panel and Restart/Shut Down/Log Out are disabled.
    .DisableHideApplication    |   // Application "Hide" menu item is disabled.
    .AutoHideToolbar           |
    .FullScreen

let optionsDictionary = [NSFullScreenModeApplicationPresentationOptions: presOptions]

browserWindowController.containerView.enterFullScreenMode(NSScreen.mainScreen()!, withOptions: optionsDictionary)
```

This gives me an error on the last line of:

```
Cannot invoke 'enterFullScreenMode' with an argument list of type '(NSScreen, with Options: [String : NSApplicationPresentationOptions])'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSFullScreenModeApplicationPresentationOptions), the corresponding value for the
key
`NSFullScreenModeApplicationPresentationOptions`
is an instance of `NSNumber` containing an unsigned integer value of `NSApplicationPresentationOptions`, so this should work:

```
let optionsDictionary = [NSFullScreenModeApplicationPresentationOptions : 
                         NSNumber(unsignedLong: presOptions.rawValue)]
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked great. The "rawValue" property is something I saw but it didn't strike me to use it that way.